# javascript selector only value of parent element

Tags: javascript

how do I extract the content from this HTML elements:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">399&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span>
</span>
```

I would like to get the price (which here is 399).

```
var number_price = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount");
```

I gets the hole elements include parent and child HTML elements. I would like to get only the number 399 here.

Answer (score 1):

Read the text and parse it as a number. It will be fine as long as the number is the start of the string.

```js
var number_price = parseFloat(document.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount").textContent);
console.log(number_price)
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">399&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text from the `firstChild`, which is a text node.

```js
const number_price = document.querySelector(".woocommerce-Price-amount");
console.log(number_price.firstChild.textContent.trim());
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">399&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I do use textContent and firstChild but forgot about the trim part. Thank you, thank you.